# Excel get Rows where one column is the same but another is different

Tags: excel

I have big volume of data in excel and I am looking to extract some records from it and just wondering the best way to do it. For instance if the data was:

```
acc no.          id
1234             10
4321             10
1234             11
4321             10
```

I would want to extract the following only:

```
acc no.          id
1234             10
1234             11
```

Is there a simple way of doing this? I tried a pivot table but the volume of data is too large for it to be represented this way.

Thanks in advance. Also sorry I could not work out how to show a table in this post.

Answer (score 1):

Use a helper column with a COUNTIFS():

In a third column put the following formula in the second row:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,"<>"  & B2)>0
```

Then copy or drag down.

This will fill a column with TRUE/FALSE

[image]

Then filter on the third Column being TRUE

[image]

Comment: Hi Scott this looks like it will work perfectly. I will try it out now and get back to you